# jquery: dynamic ID parent selector, childrens fit to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my first question!

I'm working on a healthcare app and the code is very dynamic, sometimes I have 1 column and sometimes I've 4 so I'm using an incremental Id selector (i)
Inside this container I've divs that can be 1 to 4...
if there are only one the height might be 100%, if it is three 33%.. and so on..

What I need is to fit the content div to his parent container (i).
The problem is that I need and specific function for each column

It cant be solved by CSS because my clients are in a very old version of IE

```
<div id="column-1"><!--"1" is dynamic -->
    <div id="row-1"></div>
    <div id="row-2"></div>
    <div id="row-3"></div>
    <!-- number of rows is dynamic -->
</div>
```

PS: tomorrow I'll edit with the real code, and sorry for my english ;)

Comment: I suggest to delete this question now. You can edit it, and undelete later, when it's ready. Make sure to read [ask]

Comment: What is you would want to do?? Is it you want do define height according to the row value using jquery??

Comment: What kind of browser doesn't support stylesheet? that is before IE3. Really?

Comment: @ParijatPurohit I told that to not recomend Flexbox or display-table, or height 100%.

Comment: @sagarchapagain Yes Sagar, What I need is to fit the content div to his parent container (i). In 1 column it can be only one row, but in column 2 it can be 3 rows, and in column 3 two rows. So I need to always exand the row to complete the height.

Comment: which server site are you using?? and if in server side  can you already find number of child elements while you are in loop in column??Please explain a scenerio what your issues is to provide you best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the DOM height and then use 'overflow-y' CSS property to get scroller, if your

list grows.

## column-1 {

```
height: 110px; 

overflow-y: overflow;
```

}